# Switching back to 'production' version of Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore, beta-seed-program

Prior to Yosemite release I had installed the developer preview build on my Macbook. However, even after the public release I continue to get 'beta' updates from Apple (see included screenshot). How do I prevent this, and go back to the de-facto public version?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → App Store → Change… → Do Not Show Pre-release Updates

[image]